# RichTextFX set text value of CodeArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, richtextfx

I'm just starting to use RichTextFX, and I'm trying to replace a TextArea with a CodeArea. Now TextArea has a setText() method, but I don't see anything analogous to that in CodeArea.

How can I set the text of my CodeArea?

Comment: It has `replace(...)` and `replaceText(...)` which I believe is what you want. Link: http://fxmisc.github.io/richtext/javadoc/0.6.10/org/fxmisc/richtext/TextEditingArea.html#replaceText-javafx.scene.control.IndexRange-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thank you. Seems like an awkward way to do that though.